# show error if exists duplicate data and not show for null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want when user do insert duplicate data(Code Value) show error for user and when user insert null value allow to user.

my code work for duplicate code but when user null value i want not show error and allow to user for insert data.

my code is:

```
IF  EXISTS (
        SELECT cd.Code 
        FROM chqDocuments cd
        INNER JOIN chqDocumentTypes cdt
            ON cdt.ID = cd.chqDocumentTypeID

        INNER JOIN chqDocumentTypeClassifications cdtc 
            ON cdtc.ID = cdt.chqDocumentTypeClassificationID

        WHERE
        (cd.Code = @Code )  AND 
        cdtc.id = @chqDocumentTypeClassificationID_Entry And 
        (LTRIM(RTRIM(cdtc.Code))='11' OR LTRIM(RTRIM(cdtc.Code))='12')

    )

BEGIN
    RAISERROR('showerror',16,1) 
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: Is @Code the code value that the user is inputting?  Also, is it correct to assume that this code does not currently work for NULL values, or are you just trying to make sure that it will work properly for NULL values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that @Code is the code value that the user is inputting, this code will work as-is since the following code will never evaluate to a true statement:

```
cd.Code = NULL -- even NULL != NULL; NULL IS NULL only works
```

Since that statement is never satisfied, the EXISTS clause will never be satisfied either.  Thus, the user will be allowed to input NULL values for code without an error being thrown.